# Generating SQL prepared statements with Javascript tagged template literals

Tags: javascript, security

I have put together some [code](https://gist.github.com/ducaale/61f8e58ca53e87d6d932236a9edea8b9) to generate SQL prepared statements

```js
const sql = (string, ...values) => {
  const isQuery = query =>
    query.hasOwnProperty('text') && query.hasOwnProperty('values')

  let text = ''
  for (const [i, s] of string.entries()) {
    text += s
    if (i !== string.length - 1) {
      if (isQuery(values[i])) {
        text += values[i].text
      } else if (Array.isArray(values[i])) {
        text += values[i].map(v => '?').join(', ')
      } else {
        text += '?'
      }
    }
  }

  return {
    text,
    values: values.flatMap(v => isQuery(v) ? v.values : v)
  }
}
```

which can be used like this

```js
const name = 'ali'
const ids = [10, 20, 30]
const subquery = sql`select count(*) from users where id in (${ids})`
const query = sql`select id, (${subquery}) as rank from users where name = ${name}`
console.log(query)
// {
//   text: 'select id, (select count(*) from users where id in (?, ?, ?)) as rank from users where name = ?',
//   values: [ 10, 20, 30, 'ali' ]
// }
```

The current problem as [pointed out by someone](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/g83tk8/generating_sql_prepared_statements_with/foll7zu?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) is that my code assumes nested queries to be an object which can be exploited. For example:

```js
const name = {text: `'a'; delete * from users`, values: []}
console.log(sql`select count(*) from users where name = ${name}`)
// {
//   text: "select count(*) from users where name = 'a'; delete * from users",
//   values: []
// }
```

What would be the best way to guard against that? can this be solved by Javascript symbols? and are there other security problems lurking in my code?

Comment: What problem exactly to solve depends on where the interpolated values come from.

Comment: @Bergi, interpolated values will come from users but in some cases, it could be a subquery from a programmer. So my question was if there is a way to distinguish between objects generated by SQL tagged template literal from normal values supplied by users?

Comment: Who is a user, and how do the construct these values? If the user could only supply plain  strings, but never objects, your code already would be secure. If the user is totally unlimited, and indistinguishable from a programmer, then you cannot make it secure. So, how are the user values limited?

Comment: let say we have a basic express app that has POST endpoint accepting a username and a password. If we add [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) middleware, this will mean values supplied by users could potentially be converted into JSON and we will have yet another vector of attack that needs to be guarded against.

Comment: So yes, if body-parser only accepts JSON, then using symbols would a reasonable guard.